# AJAX Post via jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my first time using AJAX. I'm Trying to write data from an HTML form to a phpmyadmin database. I'm using jQuery for the AJAX call. I suspect there's something wrong in the jQuery because I've included a Javascript `alert` with `echo` at the top of the `registerUser.php` file and it won't appear when I attempt to run this code, so the PHP is not even running. No Javascript errors in the browser. I appreciate your insight.

```
function registerUserViaAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "registerUser.php",
    data: {
      registerUsername: $('#registerUsername').val(),         
      registerPassword: $('#registerPassword').val(), 
      registerPassword: $('#registerEmail').val() 
    } 
  })
}
```

```html
<label>Username</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="text" id="registerUsername">

<label>Password</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="password" id="registerPassword">

<label>Confirm Password</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="password" id="registerConfirmPassword">

<label>Email Address</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="text" id="registerEmail">

<button class="w3-btn w3-green" style="margin-top:3%;margin-bottom:3%" id="registerButton" onclick="registerUserViaAjax()">Go</button>
```

```php
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pw  = '';
    $db = 'fall2167';

    $dbc = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db)
        or die('LOCAL CONNECT ERROR: '. mysqli_connect_error());

    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['registerUsername']);
    $pword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['registerPassword']);
    $pword = password_hash($pword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['registerEmail']);

    $check = mysqli_query($dbc, "select id from hw6 where uname = '$uname'")
        or die('confirm6 read error: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($check) != 0)
    {
        echo "<script> usernameTaken(); </script>";
        exit;
    }

    $query = "insert into users(uname, pword, email)" . "values('$uname','$pword','$email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('DB Write Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

    echo "<script> openSuccessMessage(); </script>";
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: `I've included a Javascript alert with echo at the top of the registerUser.php file and it won't appear when I attempt to run this code` This is to be expected - the AJAX request is run on the server. JS code you put in the endpoint will be ignored. To help you we need to see two things - the output of the console when you run the AJAX request, and your PHP code in registerUser.php

Comment: Also note that you're sending the same property twice - `registerPassword`. Because of this the first one, from `$('#registerPassword').val()` will be over-written.

Comment: Can you please post your php code one more thing, Are you pointing to right url ?

Comment: @Amir I've edited the post to include the PHP.

Comment: Did you try to echo $uname and other variables ? Do you get anything ?

Comment: @Amir did the echo after the variables were declared and did not get any output.

Comment: I can't see form declared in the html. Did you declared that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `done` and `fail` callbacks to make sure what happen and what is the response you're getting back from the server side :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "registerUser.php",
  data: {registerUsername: $('#registerUsername').val(), registerPassword: $('#registerPassword').val(), registerPassword: $('#registerEmail').val() },
})
  .done(function(response) {
   alert( response );

   //call you function 'openSuccessMessage' here
   openSuccessMessage(); 
})
  .fail(function(response) {
  alert( response );
});
```

Your `openSuccessMessage` should be called in the callback and not inside the PHP code.

**NOTE :** Add `try{ }catch(){}` in your PHP code to debug the instructions and show the response in alert as shown in the above code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oddly enough, it returned "success".  However, still no data to the DB.  Must be something within the php.

Comment: So try to add a try and catch to your php code to debug and make sure what really happen there.

Comment: Check my update, i suggest to call your js function inside the callback.

Comment: passed in response as the parameter and got an error "response is not defined".

Comment: Have you added the responce in anonymous function `done(function(response) {`.

Comment: Sure did.  Turned out to be some silly mistakes on my part but your hints helped me debug big time.  Got it working out. Cheers